# How to get the element inside an iframe dynamically by hovering the iframe

Tags: iframe

I need to get the element which is inside the iframe by hovering over the element for example if the button is available inside the iframe means i need to get the button element.

I have used query selector (:hover) to get the hovered element but I am able to get the elements upto iframe only from the top document. I cannot able to get the element inside the iframe.

Has any one come across this?

Answer (score 0):

It is restricted by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (so generally you can not observe widgets included from 3rd-party sites this way), but otherwise doable in recent browsers, you just have to work with the [`contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) of the `iframe`, and perhaps use [`elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint).

Example `frame.html`:

```
<div>Test1</div>
<div>Test2</div>
<div>Test3</div>
<div>Test4</div>
<div>Test5</div>
```

And containing `test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script>
      function startup(){
        frame.contentWindow.document.addEventListener("click",function(event){
          frame.contentWindow.document
            .elementFromPoint(event.clientX,event.clientY).innerHTML+="!";
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="startup()">
    <iframe id="frame" width="300" height="200" src="frame.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Click on the elements of the `iframe` and their content will get appended with exclamation marks.